# Принцип многопоточности в Java

Tags: многопоточность, java

Здравствуйте. Не могу разъяснить для себя принцип организации и работы потоков в Java. Постараюсь вкратце объяснить суть проблемы. Есть класс `MyClass`:

```
public MyClass {
   public void method1(int n) {
      int c = method2(n);
      // Ещё что-то
   }
   public int method2(int n) {
     // что-то делает
   }
}
```

Создаю единственный экземпляр этого класса под названием `myObject`.
Создаю `Runnable`, в который передаю ссылку на мой объект и в run() выполняю следующие действия:

```
public void run() {
   while (true) {
      myobject .method2(someInt);
   }
}
```

После чего запускаю несколько потоков с этим `Runnable`. Обратите внимание, что методы не синхронизированы, вообще ничего не синхронизировано. Первый поток заходит в метод1 и вычисляет С = С1, после чего вытесняется, после этого в метод1 заходит второй поток, считает С= С2 и вытесняется. После этого просыпается первый поток и продолжает выполнение метода1, чему будет равно значение C для продолжающегося потока #1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C1. Ведь C - локальная переменная.

PS: разумеется, если method2 не имеет побочного эффекта, а то иначе сам процесс вычисления c будет подвергнут гонке.
И кстати этот вопрос не по организации потоков в Java, а вообще многопоточности.

Comment: ок,этот вопрос был как бы упрощенной версией следующего.Целесообразно ли использовать один и тот же инстанс httpклиента для рассылки реквестов из разных потоков, при этом отправку самого реквеста не синхронизировать ?

Comment: Это зависит от того, какой HTTP-клиент вы используете. Но в общем случае нет, не целесообразно. Apache HTTP client имеет некоторые компоненты, которые можно шарить между разными реквестами и разными потоками.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Я использую netty. Пробежался по нему дебагом, вроде везде используются локальные переменные, не собираюсь так делать, просто стало интересно мнение более опытных в этом деле людей. Если для самой отправки используются только локальные переменные, т.е. сокет сохраняется в лок. переменной и тд то чисто теоретичесеи *такое* должно работать?

Comment: Теоретически да. Но на практике так делать не стоит если в документации явно не написано, что они гарантируют безопасность. В противном случае они в любой момент могут передумать и ваше приложение развалится на части.

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснения